# How to replace numbers by letters in a special way?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

There are few sublists:

```
lists = {{0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {0,1,1}, {1,0,0}, {1,0,1}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,1}}
```

The goal is to put A if the first element of a sublist is 1, B if the second element of a sublist is 1, C is the third element of a sublist is one, 1 if all elements of a sublists equals to 0. 
So the result should be:

```
{1, C, B, BC, A, AC, AB, ABC}
```

Honestly, I don't even know how to approach this problem. So I would be happy if you help me tackle it.

Comment: What is the context this problem comes from? It calls to mind binary numbers so there might be some direct approach rather than the one I took in my answer

Comment: This problem is from a boolean algebra, I'v got a triangle that is used to build  Zhegalkin normal form, I'm on the final step, the goal is to translate the result to "ANF".

Comment: Ah then it probably has no good correspondence in binary notation. Might be a fun way to think about it though! (e.g. think about: `FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ lists` which perhaps by chance is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` for what you gave us)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it (it's bad practice to put an involved answer in a comment so I'm moving it here):

```
lists = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,
     1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
With[{a = ToUpperCase@Alphabet[]},
 StringJoin /@ MapIndexed[If[# == 1, a[[#2[[-1]]]], ""] &, lists, {2}] /. 
  "" -> "1"
 ]

(* Out: {"1", "C", "B", "BC", "A", "AC", "AB", "ABC"} *)
```

Basically I directly translated what you said into code.

Here's a fun way that involves using the `0`/`1` as a position, extracting that, then doing the string join:

```
With[{a = Prepend[ToUpperCase@Alphabet[], ""], sublen = Length@lists[[1]]},
 Replace[
  StringJoin /@
   Partition[
    a[[
      Flatten[1 + ConstantArray[Range[sublen], Length@lists]*lists]
      ]],
    sublen
    ],
  "" -> "1",
  1
  ]
 ]
```

Some tests show that it might be minimally faster than the former

Comment: Just want to say thanks again, you were very helpful!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

```
lists.{"A", "B", "C"} /. 0 -> "1" /. Plus -> StringJoin
```

> {"1", "C", "B", "BC", "A", "AC", "AB", "ABC"}

```
% // ToExpression
```

> {1, C, B, BC, A, AC, AB, ABC}

Comment: Finally a clean method. :-)  A little shorter: `StringJoin @@@ (lists.{"A", "B", "C"} /. 0 -> "1")`

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use `ReplaceAll` (the short form of which is `/.`) with a list of rules. There are probably more concise ways of doing this that I'm not seeing.

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}} /. 
{{0, 0, 0} -> 1, {0, 0, 1} -> C, {0, 1, 0} -> B, {0, 1, 1} -> BC, 
 {1, 0, 0} -> A, {1, 0, 1} -> AC, {1, 1, 0} -> AB, {1, 1, 1} -> ABC}
(* {1,C,B,BC,A,AC,AB,ABC} *)
```

However, I would recommend surrounding each of those capital letters with quotation marks to make them strings, or else using lower case letters. All built-in functions in Mathematica begin with capital letters, and there are a number of single character capitals reserved by the system such as `C, D, E, I, K, N, and O`.

Comment: I'm sure you meant it, but `/.` is shorthand/infix notation for [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) not [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy Oops! Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
"" <> Pick[{"A","B","C"}, #, 1] & /@ lists /. "" -> 1
```

> ```
> {1, "C", "B", "BC", "A", "AC", "AB", "ABC"}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map[
 ToExpression@*StringJoin,
 Transpose[
    MapThread[
     ReplaceAll,
     {Transpose[a], {{1 -> "A"}, {1 -> "B"}, {1 -> "C"}}}
     ]
    ] /. 0 -> Nothing /. {} -> "1"
 ]
```

> {1, C, B, BC, A, AC, AB, ABC}

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety:

```
p = Position[#, 1] & /@ lists
StringJoin /@ (Extract[{"A", "B", "C"}, #] & /@ p) /. "" -> 1
```

Or using [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)

```
fun[x_] := 
 StringJoin[Reap[Sow @@@ Thread[{{"A", "B", "C"}, x}], 1][[2]]] /. 
  "" -> "1"
fun /@ lists
```

Comment: +1 for the application of `Sow`/`Reap`!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. Enjoyed your answer and kglr answer

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, 
 {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAll["" -> "1"] @
 Map[StringJoin] @
  ReplaceAll[list * Threaded[{"A", "B", "C"}], 0 :> ""]
```

{"1", "C", "B", "BC", "A", "AC", "AB", "ABC"}

Answer (score 1):

Using `ArrayRules` and `SparseArray`:

```
f[{_, 1}] := "A"
f[{_, 2}] := "B"
f[{_, 3}] := "C"
f[{_, _}] := 1

vals = Values[Reverse /@ ArrayRules[lists]];

rules = MapAt[f@# &, Map[Rule @@ ConstantArray[#, 2] &, vals], {All, 2}];

ToExpression[StringJoin @@@ Times @@@ Normal@SparseArray[rules]]

(*{1, C, B, BC, A, AC, AB, ABC}*)
```